# React only re-render changed elements in grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a grid of rectangles the state of which is managed by redux. However, when one of the rectangles has its value updated by say, incrementing a value, the entire grid is re-rendered. I can tell this because I have the color being randomly generated on the render cycle, and all of the squares color's change. However, ideally only the square that was actually updated would re-render.

[CODE SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/6zqm3z652n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use PureComponent for ListItem and update card style inside ListItem itself. this way the boxes will update one by one only when its related redux-state updated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/n33k03yxkp

Read about PureComponent and shouldComponentUpdate() function in react docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent

Comment: Excellent. Didn't even know about it. Thanks!